# Flex error on using HTTP Service

Tags: apache-flex, cross-domain

Hi I'm trying a simple tutorial of retrieving RSS feeds from yahoo and keep getting this error:

RPC Fault faultString="Security error accessing url" faultCode="Channel.Security.Error" faultDetail="Destination: DefaultHTTP"

I've seen some articles that say I need a crossdomain.xml file, but I don't really know how to set this file up and how to use it from the Flex SDK compiler (mxmlc).

Thanks

Comment: Is this a browser or desktop app?  What is the URL of the services you are trying to reach?  Is the SWF on a different host than the services?

Comment: It would help if you can post the code retrieving the RSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crossdomain.xml file needs to live at the root of the server that you are accessing.  If they have not put that there, then you are out of luck when running in the browser.  It is part of an important security aspect of running in a browser sandbox (Silverlight has the same restriction).  It is waived if you are running in Air (or pretty much anything out of the browser).

Lets say that you are trying to receive data from http://foo.com/rest/rss/all (or something like that).  You can chec quickly to see if they allow cross-site scripting (XSC) by browsing to http://foo.com/crossdomain.xml.  If it is not there, then you can't do it.

Still, the comments you got about more information would help us give you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, your answer explains it very well.